# The fixed field of the Frobenius automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Consider the algebraic closure extension $\overline{\mathbb F_q}/\mathbb F_q$, where $q=p^m$. I wonder if the fixed field of the Frobenius automorphism is $$\sigma: \overline{\mathbb F_q} \to \overline{\mathbb F_q}, a\to a^q$$ is $\mathbb F^q$.

Clearly $\sigma$ fixed $\mathbb F^q$. But does it move any other elements in $\overline{\mathbb F_q}$?

Comment: No because at most $q$ elements can satisfy $x^q=x$ in $\bar{\mathbb F_q} $

Comment: @IgnorantMathematician why is that?

Comment: Because a polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots

Comment: @IgnorantMathematician Oh I see, stupid question